# How does matlab save it's database, if it has one?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, matlab

I am working on a Java application which should read stored data from a matlab generated file containing a database. I want the database to be in SQL format with columns and rows, so that I can retrieve values in the database with Java using SQL queries. I already searched for possibilities but seem to find none.

I know that matlab can generate .mat files but can it also generate something like a .db file containing data in SQL format so that it can be read with Java using SQL queries?

Some kind of embedded database for matlab maybe?

Comment: Alternatively you could read the .mat file using [JMatIO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmatio/)?  In the projects where I had to exchange data between Matlab and Java we always used CSV, using the standard csvwrite/csvread commands and [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) on the Java side.

Comment: Would that be just as fast as SQL? And can the data in the .mat file still be reviewed by people who have no knowledge about matlab at all?

Comment: As you're merely using the files to exchange data, probably yes.  Have at look at JMatIO, it allows you to integrate reading and writing mat files from Java - I'm not sure what other ways of reviewing you are looking for?